# Differentiability of chart functions

Tags: differential-geometry, definition

In the definition of a smooth (or $C^k$) manifold the charts $\varphi: U \to \mathbb R^n$ are assumed to have the property that for any two of them $\varphi \circ \psi^{-1}$ is smooth ($C^k$).

Does $\varphi \circ \psi^{-1}$ is smooth ($C^k$) imply that both $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are smooth ($C^k$) or is it weaker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wouldn't make sense to say that $\phi$ or $\psi$ is smooth, because $U$ might not even have enough structure to make such a statement meaningful.  $U$ might not be a subset of $\mathbb R^m$, for example.  Even if $U$ is a subset of $\mathbb R^m$, typically $U$ would not be an open subset of $\mathbb R^m$.

$\phi \circ \psi^{-1}$, on the other hand, maps an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ into $\mathbb R^n$, so it is perfectly meaningful to say that $\phi \circ \psi^{-1}$ is smooth.

Comment: +1. Of course once we have established a smooth manifold structure on $U$, $\phi$ and $\psi$ are smooth by definition - a map from/to a smooth manifold is called smooth if it's smooth when appropriately (pre)composed with charts.

Comment: Thank you. "typically U would not be an open subset" -- I don't understand. It appears that $U$ is [defined to be open](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlas_(topology))?

Comment: I just edited my answer to try to be a bit more clear about that.  Suppose for example the manifold $M$ is a sphere in $\mathbb R^3$.  Then $U$ is an open subset of $M$, in the subspace topology, but $U$ is not an open subset of $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I was confused because I imagined that if you take the northpole of the sphere and an open disk around it (on the sphere) then that disk is also open in $\mathbb R^3$. But that's false. It is neither open nor closed.