# Clarification on the Definition of a Submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^N$ (and the differentiability of it's charts)

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

### Review of other questions on this site

In the following, my question is not asked/answered, with the last linked question being perhaps the most relevant

- [Clarification about Definition of Immersed Submanifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1495905/clarification-about-definition-of-immersed-submanifold)
- [Definition and clarification of submanifold, immersion and submersion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2802588/definition-and-clarification-of-submanifold-immersion-and-submersion)
- [Definition of submanifolds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4653859/definition-of-submanifolds)
- [Definition of submanifold.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2046043/definition-of-submanifold)
- [Does the construction of the tangent space of a point in a differentiable manifold require the image of charts to be Rn
  ?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4218492/does-the-construction-of-the-tangent-space-of-a-point-in-a-differentiable-manifo)
- [Differentiability of chart functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/974639/differentiability-of-chart-functions)
- [Differentiable manifolds: Definition of charts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2088029/differentiable-manifolds-definition-of-charts)
- [When is a chart of a submanifold not only a homeomorphism, but a diffeomorphism?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3747139/when-is-a-chart-of-a-submanifold-not-only-a-homeomorphism-but-a-diffeomorphism)

### Question

My question is rather simpler and is only related to a special case: on submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^N$. Specifically, looking at the definition of a submanifold in [Janich's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387986499) at page 8, where the submanifold charts are simply restrictions of certain charts of the *parent* manifold (which do preserve the topological structure), let's then proceed to the definition of the tangent space of submanifolds $M$ of $\mathbb{R}^N$ on page 26. There, as far as I understand, the **differentiability** of the charts $(U,h)$ of the $M$ **themselves** is assumed.

[image: Janich page 26]

Naturally, in the general case, the charts of differentiable manifolds are not differentiable themselves, rather only their transition maps. Further I do understand that the actual definitions of the tangent space (i.e. linear space of curve equivalence classes or linear space of derivations on germs) do not have such assumptions. Going back to submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^N$  and looking at  [Munkres' text](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201315963), where only this special case is treated, the charts on a manifold are defined as differentiable from the start (see page 196),

[image: Munkres page 196]

**I am trying to understand how (where) it is implied in Janich's book that manifold charts, when the manifold is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^N$, are differentiable.** I do have the following interpretation which I submit for your review. Guided by the following excerpt from [Spivak's volume 1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0914098705), page 30

> Normally, of course, we will suppress mention of the atlas for a differentiable manifold, and speak elliptically of the "differentiable manifold $M$"... It will always be understood that $\mathbb{R}^N$ refers to the pair $(\mathbb{R}^N,{\cal U})$

where in said text, $\cal U$ refers to the maximal atlas containing the identity chart $I(x) = x,\ x\in\mathbb{R}^N$, will it not then be the case that since $(U,h)$ of $M$ (when not restricted) is a chart of $(\mathbb{R}^N,{\cal U})$ and thus is differentiably compatible with the chart $(\mathbb{R}^N,I)$? It then follows immediately that $h$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^N$  since $h\circ I = h$ will be differentiable

### Edit 1

Please see below the Janich's definition of a submanifold

[image]

Comment: Not easy, at least for me, to understand what your precise question is.

Comment: Hi @mathcounterexamples.net, I apologise for I am new to manifolds, let me attempt to clarify: at some point in the definition of submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^N$ in Janich's book it is implied that their charts will be differentiable and I am trying to understand where. I do have a possible answer, which I have included in my question at the end. Hope this helped

Comment: Yoo should add Jänich's definition of manifold charts on submanifolds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jänich uses the same convention as Spivak. At the end of chapter 1.1 on p.3 he writes

> We also agree that, without an explicit statement to the contrary, a chart $(U,h)$ *on the manifold* $M$ always means a chart in the differentiable structure.

On $\mathbb R^N$ one has a canonical atlas $\mathfrak A(\mathbb R^N)$ consisting of the single chart $(\mathbb R^N,id_{\mathbb R^N})$. This atlas is trivially differentiable because all its charts (there is only one!)  are differentiably related.

The atlas $\mathfrak A(\mathbb R^N)$ generates the *standard differentiable structure* $\mathfrak D(\mathbb R^N)$ on $\mathbb R^N$. The charts in $\mathfrak D(\mathbb R^N)$ are precisely the $N$-dimensional charts $(U,h)$ on $\mathbb R^N$ which are differentiably related to $id_{\mathbb R^N}$. The map $h$ is a homeomorphism $h : U \to U'$  between open subsets of $\mathbb R^N$. The two transition functions between $(U,h)$ and $(\mathbb R^N,id_{\mathbb R^N})$ are
$$h \circ id_{\mathbb R^N}^{-1} : id_{\mathbb R^N}(U \cap \mathbb R^N) \to  
h(U \cap \mathbb R^N) \tag{1}$$
and
$$id_{\mathbb R^N} \circ h^{-1} : h(U \cap \mathbb R^N) \to  
id_{\mathbb R^N} (U \cap \mathbb R^N) \tag{2} .$$
But $U \cap \mathbb R^N = U$, thus the transition functions are nothing else than $h : U \to U'$ and $h^{-1} : U' \to U$. By the definition of "differentiably related" both must be $C^\infty$. In other words, $h$ must be a diffeomorphism in the sense of classic multilinear calculus.

Comment: Paul, thank you for your answer which also helps the understanding of the general context